# Non-English recommendations of books on mathematical and theoretical statistics or probability?

Tags: discussion, references

There is a large number of questions asking for recommendations of textbooks and material on these fields. Unsurprisingly, given the language of this site and most of its audience, resources are limited to material in English.

I would assume there must be a breadth of untranslated material from countries with a mathematical tradition (such as **French** or **Russian**) that is never mentioned in these threads. (*I am personally interested on French and Spanish sources but I'd rather have this open-question be a general repository for **any language**.*) Thus:

### Which non-English hidden gems could you recommend for (self?-)studying mathematical or theoretical statistics or probability?

Comment: I suggest to turn this question into a community wiki. The question is incredibly broad (and also a bit vague), and has no definite answer.

Comment: When I call the question 'vague' then this is because the question asks for resource recommendations with the goal of *"(self?-)studying mathematical or theoretical statistics or probability"*. It is not clear what that means. 1) Are we looking for an introduction text (shouldn't any university have several options), or are we looking for some interesting classical landmark articles? 2) What language is this question about?

Comment: I like digging through old texts and in a question like this [Reference: who introduced the tilde "~" notation to mean "has probability distribution..."?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531826) I encountered French and Russian resources. Are those the type of 'gems' that you are looking for? (Or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/596865/164061) when looking for the origin of the Neyman Pearson Lemma).

Comment: Many of the Russian texts/monologues have been translated in English with dedication, right from Kolmogorov's days to Shiryaev, Pfanzagl.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thanks for the migration. I was also unsure where would this question best be located (but since all book recommendations questions were in the standard site, assumed this was no different). Regarding which type of gems I am looking for, I am looking for texts one would use to learn or study, rather than texts that have primarily a historical value.

Comment: @Kuku It wasn't me that did the migration. But one of the moderators, so cheers to them. ... Sidenote: we get regularly questions that don't fit in but are still interesting. So your question may still be interesting. But SE is not a forum or a chatbox that relates to *all* interesting questions, instead it is a question and answer website.

Comment: *"I am looking for texts one would use to learn or study, rather than texts that have primarily a historical value"* This is not so clear to me. Are you asking a question like "what are standard statistics textbooks in non-english?". I imagined that you were looking for something more complex because you were referring to French and Russian as sources of traditional literature. But, you are not looking for scientific literature?

Comment: I am very sorry, but this is not a question for our Meta site -- and it is too broad and tangential for the main site (where it was originally posted).

Comment: @whuber Given that there are multiple questions asking for recommendations of books for self-study on mathematical statistics or probability in the main site, what makes this question 'too broad and tangential'? Would it be sufficient to limit it to a single language, say, French? If not, why?

Comment: "Tangential" because SE sites not devoted to a foreign language are specifically English only and "too broad" because it has no focus whatsoever: it essentially asks for a list of any non-English material anybody might have found useful or interesting about anything related to statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I do find this an interesting but also troubling question.

As a question on the main website this question is too broad, as generating a non-english library of resources is too broad in the topics and the languages.

However, the question is interesting in challenging the concept of English as lingua franca (Ironically a non-english term) for the use in statistics, science and technology.

A problem with the question is that, also on meta, it is not very clear.

I know several languages and statistical writings in different languages asside from English (Dutch, German, French), but I have no clue about how to answe this question (Because it is broad and general).

Comment: Equivalent questions that are restricted (implicitly or explicitly) to English are abundant in the main site though, despite not having a clear-cut defined answer. What is precisely the rationale for the difference in treatment?

Comment: @Kuku there are several literature request questions, but they are the borderline of on-topic here. They should not be regarded as the standard. In that direction of type of questions (demand for resources) one needs to be very specific in order to make the question slip through the cracks. A similar thing is going on when people ask for code specific solution.